# JavaFX TextField to Int

Tags: java, javafx, integer

i had a problem with this code here, just wanna make a small calculator:
    package application;

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
//import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            //BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Root.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @FXML
    private TextField textField, textField2;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    protected void onClick(ActionEvent event) {
        textField.getText();
        textField2.getText();
        textField = Integer.parseInt(textField);
        textField2 = Integer.parseInt(textField2);
        label = textField + textField2;
        label = Integer.toString(label);
        label.setText(label.getText());
    }
}
```

so i got a problem when i tryed to calcul 1 and 1... I cant copy the out put bcs its too long, try this code on your pc to get the output, and i think the problem is the Integer.

Edit:output here:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (TextField)
    The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (TextField)
    The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) 
javafx.scene.control.TextField, javafx.scene.control.TextField
    The method toString(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Label)

at application.Main.onClick(Main.java:44)
... 58 more
```

ok so here the the outputs does that helps more?
Edit2:FXML here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" 
minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="278.0" prefWidth="473.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="application.Main">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="textField" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="54.0" 
prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="126.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="textField2" layoutX="174.0" layoutY="54.0" 
prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="126.0" />
      <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="323.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="42.0" 
prefWidth="126.0" text="Label" />
      <Button layoutX="174.0" layoutY="162.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
onAction="#onClick" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="126.0" text="Sum" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

so here you can run the program.

Comment: That doesn't compile. Even if it did, no one can run it without the FXML.

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code 1) you don't `Integer.parseInt` can't take a TextField as parameter 2)TextField can be assigned by an Integer 3) Label can't be assigned by two TextFields or a String this is what I can see

Comment: You can copy the output if you put it in a code block

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code until you have a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem? This will increase your chances of getting good answers by a lot!

Comment: James_D i am new to Java just trying some thing new

Comment: Lonly Neuron its too long the output

Comment: 2 Edits, i got the output and the FXML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you on your way to understanding what is going on, good luck:

```
protected void onClick(ActionEvent event) {
    // getText() returns type String
    String text1 = textField.getText();
    String text2 = textField2.getText();
    // parse() returns type int or Integer
    int int1 = Integer.parseInt(text1);
    int int2 = Integer.parseInt(text2);
    // using Integer here so we can use toString() next
    Integer result = int1 + int2;
    // setText() takes input of type String
    label.setText(result.toString());
}
```